# Running Scripts at Startup

Tags: server, scripts, startup

I'm trying to run a few scripts (MongoDB and Leanote) at startup but am running into a bit of difficulty. I have a file named leanote in:

```
/etc/init.d/leanote.sh
```

I also ran:

```
update-rc.d leanote.sh defaults 100
```

From what I understand this should run at the startup of the system, however I'm having problems where it doesn't appear to be running. Here is the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
su - keith -c mongod --dbpath /home/keith/data/ --logpath /home/keith/log/mongodb.log --logappend --fork &
su - keith -c sh /home/keith/leanote/bin/run.sh
```

No matter what I try, I can't seem to figure out why it's not running at startup. I'm able to check this by running mongo and it can't make a connection meaning that it doesn't appear to be running.

I tried following the guide [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html), and added the su portion as I thought it was running as root instead of my local user, although I'm not sure if that matters.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Just to help simplify, you can use `sudo install scriptname.sh /path/to/script/scriptname` and then run `scriptname` from anywhere to run that script. Not an answer but could help with getting them to run, or at least make it easier if they won't autostart.

Comment: What release and version of Ubuntu are you running? Xubuntu 16.04?

Comment: @PSmith I tried the install and no, I can't run the script from anywhere unless I am doing something wrong. I tried running: `keith@leanote:/etc/init.d$ sudo install leanote.sh /home/keith/leanote/bin/run.sh` then got command not found when i tried running `leanote`.

Comment: @StandardEyre Ubuntu Server 16.04.

Comment: You need to remove the `.sh` on that to install the script. So: `sudo install myscript.sh /path/to/script/mycommand` ... notice there's no `.sh` on there, so you'd just run that like `mycommand`. But it might not be exactly what you need, not sure

Answer (score 0):

I decided as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# /etc/init.d/leanote

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

     case "$1" in

 start)
     echo "Starting LEANOTE..."
     bash /home/keith/leanote/bin/run.sh &
     ;;

 stop)
     echo "Stoping LEANOTE..."
     pkill leanote
     ;;

 *)

     echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
     exit 1

esac

exit 0
```

Permission to run:

```
chmod +x leanote
```

Insert at system startup :

```
update-rc.d leanote defaults
```